# Deduce the multiplicities of a transformation from a block diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

In Chapter 8 (*part B*) from the book "*Linear Algebra Done Right*", the author mentioned that if a transformation $T$ has the following block diagonal matrix $A$ with respect to some given bases:

$$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 7 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $T$ has 3 eigenvalues 4, 2, and 1 with multiplicities (or algebraic multiplicity) 1, 2, 2 respectively. But I don't understand why the multiplicities have to be 1, 2, 2?

For your reference, this is the definition of multiplicity in the book:

> Suppose $T$ is a the linear functional in $L(V)$. The multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$ is defined to be the dimension of the corresponding generalized eigenspace $G(\lambda, T)$.

Where $G(\lambda, T)$ is the generalized eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$.

Comment: You can use the given basis to decompose $\mathbb{C}^5$  as the direct sum of $T$ invariant subspaces on which $T$ acts in a specific way (which can be read off from the matrix), the result then follows by identifying these subspaces with the generalized eigenspaces.

Comment: Ohm that is indeed very simple. How stupid I am. Thanks so much!

Comment: @jd27 please make it an answer, I'm ready to accept it.